# How can i send response to a request without having HttpServletresponse

Tags: http, jsp, servlets

Hi please some one help me in this issue.

I have a class which extends HttpServlet and a method called doGet(HttpServletRequest request)

But i dont have a HttpServletResponse .Now i want to respond to a request from a client as im not having response how can i respond to a request.Can i create able to create it dynamically in that class using reflections and is their any other way..My problems pseudo code looks as follows

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request)throws ServletException, IOException {//having only request as parameter in doGet()
   //Want to respond to a jsp with out having a response 
   //how can i create a response object if i got a HttpServletResponse response the code looks as follows 

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    if(name.equals("James")&& password.equals("abc")){
    response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
  }
  else{
  pw.println("u r not a valid user");
  }
}
```

Comment: Started Posting issues from past 1 week...!!!!

Comment: Yea will try to format...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException`

The method signature is:

`protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException`

Comment: Ok fine...Abu,my scenario be like this my class is getting requests from number of clients..and in my class im having two methods let it be A() and B() after doing some computations in those methods i have to sent my response to a jsp based on request..how can i sent without having response ...can i create it instantly..any way let me know

Comment: @babuchitti the point is you should override the correct method, then you'll have the `response` available as an argument.

Comment: Fine @JanDvorak im getting request object from a client and im doing some processing and sending response to a jsp..im not at all using doGet(Http... req,Http...res)//simple not ovveriding.In this case how can i respond for a request from a normal methods like A() or B()...

Comment: @babuchitti then in your case define a method with a return type `String` and return a string value that you need to display on the jsp